# How can you install a package using catkin build?

Tags: ros-melodic, catkin-make, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use a script from the package bag_tools (http://wiki.ros.org/bag_tools?distro=hydro#make_video.py)

First instruction is to :

```
catkin_make install --pkg bag_tools
```

However I had made my workspace using **catkin build**.  (I'm not aware of the details of the difference between catkin_make and catkin build).
How do I install bag_tools using catkin build?

TL;DR: What's the catkin build equivalent of "catkin_make install --pkg bag_tools"

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331276/how-can-you-install-a-package-using-catkin-build?/) by [ambareesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/44870/ambareesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2019-08-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Any time I need to find out the equivalent `catkin_tools` command for a `catkin_make` command (or vice versa), I consult [this really handy table](https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration.html#cli-comparison-with-catkin-make-and-catkin-make-isolated).

In this case, it tells me the command you want is `catkin config --install` followed by `catkin build`.

You can check if installation has been set by just running `catkin config` and viewing the output.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2019-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8